# How to make a Report visible to reporters in a project

Tags: youtrack

I cant find a way to make a report visible to anyone but the creator of the report.

The following link is only visible to the user who create the report.

[image: youtrack report page]

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This feauture is not available in YouTrack 5.x or less.

It is planned for YouTrack 6.0 release along with new report types. http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/nextversion/

Currently it is available for preview in EAP program:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TSYSPUB/YouTrack+EAP+Builds